# How to get language expansion in Textblob python language detection library

Tags: python, textblob

I need a language detection script. I tried Textblob library which right now give me the two letter abbreviation of the language. How can I get the complete language expansion?

This detects the language with two letter abbreviation of the language

```
from textblob import TextBlob
b = TextBlob("cómo estás")
language = b.detect_language()
print(language)
```

Actual Results : es  
Expected Results : Spanish

I have the list of language and their abbreviation from this link 
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/languages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you're using gives you a two-letter abbreviation that conforms to the `ISO 639-2` international protocol. You could look up a list of these correspondences (e.g. [this page](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/IG/ert/iso639.htm) and rig up a method to just input one and output the other, but given you're programming in python, someone's already done that for you.

I recommend [`pycountry`](https://pypi.org/project/pycountry/) - a general-purpose library for this type of task that also contains a number of other standards. Example of using it for this problem:

```
from textblob import TextBlob
import pycountry
b = TextBlob("நீங்கள் எப்படி இருக்கிறீர்கள்")
iso_code = b.detect_language()  
# iso_code = "ta"
language = pycountry.languages.get(alpha_2=iso_code)
# language = Language(alpha_2='ta', alpha_3='tam', name='Tamil', scope='I', type='L')
print(language.name)
```

and that prints `Tamil`, as expected. Same works for Spanish:

```
>>> pycountry.languages.get(alpha_2='es').name
'Spanish'
```

and probably most other languages you'll encounter in whatever it is you're doing..

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for sharing

Comment: It shows error message:  File "C:\Users\makta\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 649, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)

HTTPError: Not Found

Comment: @tursunWali appears the issue is with textblob, [and is reported here](https://github.com/sloria/TextBlob/issues/397). You can try using another translation library instead, which might have a similar `detect_language()` method.